# Singleton or dependency injection

Tags: ios, dependency-injection, singleton

I am working on a Restkit app where there is a `RKManagedObjectStore`. At the moment, I've configured a singleton store in the traditional way and accessed the store in my `UIViewController` s like so:

```
[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]
```

However, now I'm thinking that all my controllers are going to be implicitly dependant on me configuring this shared singelton instance in my application delegate. Would it make better design sense to, instead of using the `defaultStore`, inject an instance of `RKManagedObjectStore` in-between controllers?

Can someone explain the pros and cons of using a singleton shared instance vs. dependency injection and vice-versa, in an iPhone app?

Comment: There is a project on Github works around dependency injection container for Objective-C,some discuss between injection and singleton by the author :https://github.com/jasperblues/Typhoon#what-is-dependency-injection

Comment: Ooo that actually looks awesome, I'll give it a whirl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to not do either. In part this is because of the use of RestKit, meaning that it's the interface between your internal and the external data models. As such, I like to create a custom singleton which wraps up all of this logic. It provides an interface in terms of my internal data model and handles all of the remote interaction and mapping through RestKit. When using Core Data this singleton can also be used to mediate access to the context.

Comment: Covering what specifically? It's a standard singleton with public methods for getting and updating model objects and providing access to the context for fetched results controllers.

Comment: But why are you using it as a Singleton? Why not inject it into your controllers? This is what I'm struggling with: what are the benefits of using a Singleton to access Dependencies rather than inject them?

Comment: Because no one instance knows about all of the view controllers. I could chain the dependency injection but it's usually more code / things to remember. Also, I may have to inject into a class where it isn't required just to get it to one that is...